# Im not getting desired accuracy in logistic regression on MNIST

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, logistic-regression

I'm not getting output on logistic regression problem. I have used MNIST dataset to predict the number digit,
I have used Adam optimizer, It is not giving the desired accuracy.Model Reduces cost but does not give accuracy well.

My code looks like this.

```
# In[1]:


import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')


# In[2]:


train_x = mnist.train.images
train_y = mnist.train.labels

X = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,784],dtype=tf.float32,name="X")
Y = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,10],dtype=tf.float32,name="Y")


# In[3]:


#hyperparameters

training_epoches = 25
batch_size = 1000
total_batches = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784,10]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([10]))


# In[6]:


y_ = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X,W)+b)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y*tf.log(y_), reduction_indices=1))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


# In[7]:


with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoches in range(training_epoches):
        for i in range(total_batches):
            xs_batch,ys_batch = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            sess.run(optimizer,feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y})
        print("cost after epoch %i : %f"%(epoches+1,sess.run(cost,feed_dict={X:train_x,Y:train_y}))) 

    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_, 1), tf.argmax(Y, 1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({X: mnist.test.images, Y: mnist.test.labels}))
```

The output of code is :

```
cost after epoch 1 : 0.005403
cost after epoch 2 : 0.002935
cost after epoch 3 : 0.001866
cost after epoch 4 : 0.001245
cost after epoch 5 : 0.000877
cost after epoch 6 : 0.000652
cost after epoch 7 : 0.000507
cost after epoch 8 : 0.000407
cost after epoch 9 : 0.000334
cost after epoch 10 : 0.000279
cost after epoch 11 : 0.000237
cost after epoch 12 : 0.000204
cost after epoch 13 : 0.000178
cost after epoch 14 : 0.000156
cost after epoch 15 : 0.000138
cost after epoch 16 : 0.000123
cost after epoch 17 : 0.000111
cost after epoch 18 : 0.000100
cost after epoch 19 : 0.000091
cost after epoch 20 : 0.000083
cost after epoch 21 : 0.000076
cost after epoch 22 : 0.000070
cost after epoch 23 : 0.000065
cost after epoch 24 : 0.000060
cost after epoch 25 : 0.000056
Accuracy: 0.1859
```

It is giving Accuracy of 0.1859.which is not expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use - `y_ = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(X,W)+b)`

instead of :

`y_ = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X,W)+b)`

as the MNIST data set has multi-class labels (sigmoid is used in case of 2 classes).

You may also need to add a small number to

`cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y*tf.log(y_), reduction_indices=1))`

like -

`cost = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(Y*tf.log(y_ + 1e-10), reduction_indices=1))`

in case the cost results in nan